# SQL Server - loss of indexes scenario

Tags: sql-server

Note: Not sure if SO has a specific DB site so I'm putting this question here.

SQL Server 2008 Enterprise.

I'm working to resolve many issues with a database that is 450gb. I'm trying to first get the size of the mdf down so that backups can actually take place. For some very large tables I'm moving indexes to a different file group (which hopefully can be moved to a separate drive later on) in an attempt to get the mdf size down.

My question is, let's say that I have all indexes in a separate file group, not part of the mdf and only the mdf is being backed up. If the system went down and a backup had to be restored, what is the worst case scenario if none of the index file groups were backed up?

I'm assuming that things would be ok but SQL would have to rebuild the indexes which would cause massive slow downs for a bit.

Note: Before you blast me on bad practices, I've inherited these issues and I'm playing firefighter right now.

Comment: You might want to consider asking this on [Serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) where DBA's and SysAdmins hang out - they probably have more background and insights into matters like this.

Comment: @marc_s serverfault doesn't have nearly the traffic that SO does. Answers take a long time to get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating indexes can take a while, so if you have to recreate them all from scratch you'd potentially lose the definitions (unless properly documented) and have to spend a lot of time waiting for them to build one at a time.  Depending on the size of the tables, it can take a while for just one to be created.

I would suggest that as part of what you are doing, you look at what the indexes are actually doing and if you can remove/reduce how many you have.  A lot of times developers and DBAs build too many indexes, and a few well thought out ones can take the place of several hastily thrown together indexes.

Comment: agreed on the indexes but that is coming next. There ARE many indexes that can be removed or changed to reduce what columns are included but that will take some serious time to evaluate especially to get the value of composite indexes. So you're saying after the restore we'd have to recreate the indexes so I should script them all out then? The definitions wont be stored with the table in the mdf?

Comment: I don't know that for certain.  But when you lose a file for a database (for example) all the server can tell you is that it's trying to connect to a database at location X, and cannot.  You can't use that information to recreate it though, you have to restore from backup or start from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Brent Ozar's answer on ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/questions/1/how-to-exclude-indexes-from-backups-in-sql-server-2008

> When disaster strikes, you restore the
>   primary filegroup by itself. The data
>   is suddenly online, but the indexes
>   are not. However, to get back to
>   normalcy, you'll need to export that
>   data into a new clean database and add
>   indexes from there.

Check out the link for more details (and to give him the upvotes). He also has a link to a tutorial on doing filegroup restores.